# Anime about a guy who sees and then eats invisible bugs?

Tags: boogiepop-phantom

Can you identify this anime?

This anime might have been a short movie that was an extra on another dvd set.

It was about a guy who starts seeing these bug-like things attached to peoples backs. I think he has the urge to eat one which makes him realize that the 'bugs' are the regrets or bad memories of those people. When he eats them the people become happier. After trying to help people by eating their invisible 'bugs' he notices they might have been better off keeping those memories.

I know that's not much to go on, but any help would be great!

Comment: I remember an anime called xxxHOLiC (http://myanimelist.net/anime/861/xxxHOLiC). I think the protagonist could see "monsters" attached to people. If he took the monster away, the person would become happier. That said, they are not bugs (but some may have been shaped like bugs) and I think he probably did not eat them.

Comment: Hmm, that does have some similar elements, but after looking it up I can definitely say that was not it. The bug-like things were more physical looking (not ghost-spirity) and the story had a more serious tone. The people who were made happy then went on to do stupid things because they didn't have their regrets holding them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an episode of [Boogiepop Phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogiepop_Phantom).

Different episodes focused on different characters, each having a special ability... that was usually not as beneficial as it seemed. Their stories intertwined and showed the events from the different viewpoints of these characters. The guy who could eat bad memories was one of these episodes.

Comment: It is indeed an episode of Boogiepop Phantom. I've been rewatching the series and I seem to recall that this is episode 2. The character in question is Hisashi Jonouchi. The "bugs" he eats are memories associated with some form of guilt, remorse, or regret. When he eats them, the person no longer has the feeling of guilt, remorse, or regret, but also has forgotten the memory associated with the guilt, remorse, or regret.

Comment: Yes , that's the one! Thanks. ^-^ 
It was hard to figure out because he was a character of the week and not the whole show.